# Clang static analyzer (clazy) ignores NOLINT and similar meta instructions in Qt code

Tags: qt, warnings, clang-static-analyzer

I need to switch off some warnings that the Clang static analyzer (clazy) flags in some Qt code that I work with.

Appending '// NOLINT' as a comment to code lines that get flagged by clazy does not work, apparently because Qt is transformed to C++ code before clazy gets to see it, dispensing with all comments and pragmas. Appending '// clazy:exclude...' does not work either, and likewise with

```
#if defined(__clang__) // if that is even the right define to look for      
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-W..."
#endif
...
#if defined(__clang__)
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#endif
```

Is there any elegant way of getting rid of clazy warnings in Qt code? I would prefer it to be applicable to individual lines as opposed to disabling warnings on entire files.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<your code> // clazy:exclude=<warning>,<another warning>
```

For example, I get [clazy-strict-iterators warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9oAW.png)   in my code.

I've added `// clazy:exclude=strict-iterators` in the end of line, [and the warning is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UW0C.png).

Note that you should not add `clazy-` prefix to the warning name.

Source: https://blogs.kde.org/2016/04/25/clazy-suppressing-warnings